# How big can be tar command options

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I want to use `tar` commands to archive multiple files in multiple directories. I just want one tar file as output.

```
tar -cvf file.tar /path1/inputfile1 /path2/inputfile2 ...
```

I want to know how long can be the arguments of create `tar` command. Does `tar` have some restrictions (or) unix command can only be some char long.

Comment: `tar` doesn't have a limit of its own, but you're limited by the operating system's limit on command line length.

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit in `tar` itself, but if you put the filenames on the command line you'll be limited by the operating system's command length limit. To get around this, you can use the `-T` option to get the list of filenames to archive from a file. So put all the filenames in a file `filenames.txt` (one filename per line), and then do:

```
tar -cvf file.tar -T filenames.txt
```